# NSString *path: The first path in the code is always loaded, even when the if-else condition is false

Tags: ios, google-maps, path, kml

I am implementing an iOS application, which is basically a journey planner, and I am using a **KMLparser** in my code to read from KML files. Currently, I have a KML file for every route between two points on the map, because I want the application to be used offline. However, I faced a problem, and I was hoping someone would help me fix it.

I am using if-else conditions to decide which KML file to choose to load the map from. For testing, I created 2 KML files and 2 if-else conditions.

I am using **NSString *path** to read the KML files. The problem here is that the first path is always taken no matter what the if-else condition is. I don't have any other paths that the program can read from. It's always the path that is in the first if-else condition that it reads from. If I change the KML file in the first path, the map changes accordingly, but I don't want to change KML files using the code. What's the use of GUIs then ?

I checked that the if-else conditions were working using:

```
    [self.textField2 setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"ONE"]];
```

and

```
    [self.textField2 setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"TWO"]];
```

as you can see below in the code, and it works perfectly. The output is "ONE" when the first if-else condition is true, and the output is "TWO" when the second if-else condition is true.

The problem is only in the "path". or is it ?

I have been trying so long to find a solution, but I don't know what's wrong. I'd appreciate any help from you.

Thank you!

Omran

--

### **EDIT: April 10, 2012**

So, I cleaned some of the garbage in the previous code I showed you, and below you can see the modified code. The problem still exists!

However, at least now I know what it is after using **NSLog**. As you can see, I have three if-else conditions. The problem is that the third condition (the **else**) is always loaded!

For example, let's say the first if-else condition is true, so the NSLog gives me:

```
    2012-04-10 04:55:55.234 Untitled2[7681:11903] PATH 1(null)
```

but then immediately it executes the third if-else condition, and NSLog gives me:

```
    2012-04-10 04:55:55.245 Untitled2[7681:11903] PATH 3(null)
```

Also, when the third if-else condition is true, I get:

```
    2012-04-10 04:55:55.234 Untitled2[7681:11903] PATH 3(null)
    2012-04-10 04:55:55.245 Untitled2[7681:11903] PATH 3(null)
```

So, I am really close to solving the problem. I know that **path 3** is always loaded, but I don't know why. I checked my code but I can't see why the third if-else condition is always executed.

Can anyone help with this ?

Thank you.

Omran

```
self.busstops1 = [self.busstops objectAtIndex:1];
self.busstops2 = [self.busstops objectAtIndex:2];
self.busstops3 = [self.busstops objectAtIndex:3];
self.busstops4 = [self.busstops objectAtIndex:4];
self.busstops5 = [self.busstops objectAtIndex:5];

NSString *temp = self.textField.text;
NSString *temp2 = self.textField2.text;

int countKML;

NSString *path;
NSString *path2;
NSString *path3;

[self.map retain];

NSURL *url;
[self.map removeOverlays:self.map.overlays];
[self.map removeAnnotations:self.map.annotations];

//countKML=0;
if ( [temp isEqual:self.busstops1] && [temp2 isEqual:self.busstops2] )
{
    NSLog(@"PATH 1%@",countKML);
    [self.textField2 setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"ONE"]];
    path = @"";
    path2 = @"";
    path3 = @"";

    countKML=1;
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AD Bus Map %d",countKML] ofType:@"kml"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

} 
else if ( [temp isEqual:self.busstops1] && [temp2 isEqual:self.busstops3] )
{
    NSLog(@"PATH 2%@",countKML);
    [self.textField2 setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"TWO"]];
    path = @"";
    path2 = @"";
    path3 = @"";

    countKML=2;
    path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AD Bus Map %d",countKML] ofType:@"kml"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2];

} 
else {
    NSLog(@"PATH 3%@",countKML);
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.textField2 setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"OTHER"]];
    path = @"";
    path2 = @"";
    path3 = @"";

    countKML = 0;
    path3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AD Bus Map %d",countKML] ofType:@"kml"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path3];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The route for the entered points is not available!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

kmlParser = [[KMLParser alloc] initWithURL:url];
[kmlParser parseKML];

[self.map removeOverlays:self.map.overlays];

// Add all of the MKOverlay objects parsed from the KML file to the self.map.
NSArray *overlays= [kmlParser overlays];
[self.map addOverlays:overlays];

[self.map removeAnnotations:self.map.annotations];

// Add all of the MKAnnotation objects parsed from the KML file to the self.map.
NSArray *annotations= [kmlParser points];
[self.map addAnnotations:annotations];

// Walk the list of overlays and annotations and create a MKMapRect that
// bounds all of them and store it into flyTo.
MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;


for (id <MKOverlay> overlay in overlays) {
    if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
        flyTo = [overlay boundingMapRect];
    } else {
        flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, [overlay boundingMapRect]);
    }
}

for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations) {
    MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
    MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
    if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
        flyTo = pointRect;
    } else {
        flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
    }
}

// Position the self.map so that all overlays and annotations are visible on screen.
self.map.visibleMapRect = flyTo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`isEqual:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a), not [`compare:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare%3a).

(`compare:` returns an `NSComparisonResult`, which is one of three values: `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame`, or `NSOrderedDescending`. Saying `![object1 compare:object2]` doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried it, but it didn't help fix the problem, unfortunately. It seems that the problem is that one of the if-else conditions is always executed at the end, which kind of overwrites the preceding result.